# Structure needs cleaning

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am unable to "chown" or "cd" into a some but not all home directories.

I get the following:

cd 
-bash: cd: : Structure needs cleaning.

Any suggestions?

Comment: check out these answers
https://askubuntu.com/questions/910078/help-structure-needs-cleaning-error-cannot-mount-partition
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330742/cannot-remove-file-structure-needs-cleaning

Answer (score 1):

This means that your filesystem is corrupted. You can try to use `fsck` or alike, after having unmounted it.

Comment: I encountered this today.  Used e2fsck on that partition after umount of that partition.  It showed the particular file / its inode was corrupted.  I allow the fixes to go thru, and it worked.